# What level do you unlock the HotShot Combat Rifle?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

I've picked it up a few times in battle and really liked it, but what level do you unlock it?

Comment: The Hot Shot is the default combat rifle you get on level 1. If you got one that handles differently, then it probably had some mods on it.

Answer (score 3):

Much like Assylum said. The combat rifle is unlocked at level 1 for you to purchase and begin building. The name HotShot is just taken from parts to give you an idea of what it is.

weapon naming is 3 parts:

- First part is the mag (express, extended, standard, electro, etc).
- Second part is the muzzle/scope (shrill, thundering, tactical, eagle-eye etc).
- Third part is the weapon reciever + other factors like stock, barrel, and scope (hotshot, expert, kestrel, mercenary, etc).